# Marginal plots in plotly.graph_objects.Scatter

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

In plotly.express, I can easily display marginal plots by passing the `marginal_x` and `marginal_y` parameters to the `px.scatter` method, for example:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', 
                 marginal_x="histogram", 
                 marginal_y="histogram")
```

[image]

I do not see any such parameters in the [plotly.graph_objects.Scatter](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.html) method.
How do I achieve the same result using the graph_objects API?

I have tried searching the plotly.graph_object documentation but did not find anything related to marginal plots.

Comment: `go.Scatter()` just returns a scatter trace instance, it's not the equivalent of `px.scatter()` which returns a `plotly.graph_objects.Figure`. Plotly express functions do many things behind the scene, particularly in this case (using marginal_x/y) where it creates subplots with 3 traces in one call. To accomplish the same with graph_objects, you will have to create the subplots and the 3 traces manually. To get a better idea, you could inspect the code in your IDE (eg. in vscode ctrl-click on `px.scatter` will lead you to `make_figure` etc.).

Comment: If you want to create a similar graph with a graph object, you can refer to the data structure with `print(fig.data)` and the plot settings with `print(fig.layout)` for figs created with express, so I think you can reproduce the graph using the contents of those objects.